# Vim and Windows

Tags: windows, vim, color-scheme

I've been trying to setup gVim on windows 10. I've had issues setting up the vimrc file and have deleted and reinstalled it. I can't get it to get my color scheme working and save my text font.

Does anyone have any good links to guides to setting up Vim in windows? A link to the Ubuntu download does not count!

Cheers.

Comment: Show us what you did if you want help. Otherwise, use Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by downloading a 64-bit plugin compatible version found here: https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases/tag/v8.0.0003

Inside of it, there's a useful **install.exe** file. It brings up a terminal that allows you to select some options such as, setting up a vimrc file upon your installation.

This solved my issue with the vimrc file and I now have it working the way I would like gVim to.